# Angular 7 - what is the best approach for guards

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular. I have covered a few of Angular tutorials and as a backend developer, I am wondering how it is acceptable that a user can navigate to protected templates with fake JWT... In my app, I created `/dashboard` including guard.

`{ path: 'dashboard', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}`

The body of my guard method:

```
  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.authenticationService.isAuthenticated()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

whereas *isAuthenticated* is a service method (I use `angular2-jwt` as `jwtHelper`):

```
  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (!token) { return false; }
    return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
  }
```

I can put any JWT to my local storage and it passes because it checks only if JWT has a valid format. Even if I add interceptor which forbids fetching data from server still user is able to navigate to a protected template. I don't accept that solution. What is the best approach to handle that? Does every navigation between templates (e.g `/dashboard` -> `/admin` should be requested to the server to check if the JWT is valid? If so, how to achieve that? Unless what is the best practice to make my protected templates invisible for authenticated users and make it invulnerable on fake JWT?

Comment: *I don't accept that solution*: why? Anything the user might see by cheating like that is some static HTML code that is in the bundle that is already downloaded, or data that the page fetches from the server. But the server should prevent him/her from downloading this data if the JWT token is fake. So there's no security problem. Actual security checks must be on the server. The guards exist for ergonomic reasons.

Comment: Does it really matter though? User will only view HTML without data so it shouldn't be a problem.
edit: Exactly like @JBNizet said

Comment: hmm, so it is OK if any user can go into the admin panel to check how it looks like? (I know he won't see any data but still, it's weird to me that he can do it)

Comment: If you don't want a user to even see the code of an admin panel, then make it a lazy loaded module, and prevent it to be downloaded on the server. But really, nobody cares what the admin panel looks like.

Comment: If the user is sophisticated enough to put a fake user token into local storage, he is likely sophisticated enough to change the code of your auth guard so it always returns true ...

Comment: You are right guys. I am accustomed to old full stack solutions where every page is rendered by server-side every time when a user requests that. In Angular app, it works differently.

Comment: Summarizing - I should not care about that and it is completely normal for commercial angular apps?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into JWT claims? You could put metadata in there that tells you something about the user's access rights that you could use to determine whether or not the user should have access to the route. See: https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: Well, I am not sure if you got me correctly. JWT works fine everytime it's checked on the server side. My doubt was if it's OK if the user can navigate to another protected template with fake JWT in local storage. Is it clear that for you?